# Cyrus can't connect via SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, imap, tls, cyrus

I made a key with

```
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/imap.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/private/imap.key -days 365
```

and then I make `chown cyrus /etc/ssl/certs/imap.pem` and `chown cyrus /etc/ssl/private/imap.key` after I try to connect via Thunderbird to the Server, I can't log in to it. In the mail.err I found this:

```
May 27 08:31:55 evolutio cyrus/imaps[18343]: DBERROR: error exiting application: Invalid argument
May 27 08:31:55 evolutio cyrus/imaps[18344]: unable to get private key from '/etc/ssl/certs/imap.key'
May 27 08:31:55 evolutio cyrus/imaps[18344]: TLS server engine: cannot load cert/key data, may be a cert/key mismatch?
May 27 08:31:55 evolutio cyrus/imaps[18344]: error initializing TLS
May 27 08:31:55 evolutio cyrus/imaps[18344]: Fatal error: tls_init() failed
```

in the imapd.conf I added this:

```
tls_cert_file: /etc/ssl/certs/imap.pem
tls_key_file: /etc/ssl/private/imap.key
```

How I can solve the problem?

Comment: with `openssl s_client -connect lars-dev.de:993` I get this error:
`CONNECTED(00000003)
18802:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:607:
`

Comment: Did you restart cyrus after editing the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your imapd.conf for a false filepath to imap.key, you write that the directory is /etc/ssl/private/imap.key but in your logs cyrus search in /etc/ssl/certs/ for imap.key

After that the permissions to /etc/ssl/private are wrong so your cyrus can't access the key file.

Comment: What is wrong with the `tls_key_file: /etc/ssl/private/imap.key` ? It is the right filepath. But why Cyrus try to search in /etc/ssl/certs?

Comment: maybe you has a old entry in your imapd.conf with the wrong file path.

Comment: Can you look at my imapd.conf, please. here is the SSL/TLS part: http://pastebin.com/MXfdjtt7

Comment: let us start a chat

Comment: What should be the permissions for `/etc/ssl/certs/imap.key`? Making `imap.key` not owned by `root.root` is not secure. Apache and Postfix correctly load the key before dropping the privileges.